# A simple interpolation in R

Tags: r, interpolation

This might be a very trivial problem, but when I searched for this error I got only 9 results on the Stack Overflow; none of which helped.

What is wrong with a simple interpolation between two points with `approx(c(0,0),c(0,1))`? It returns:

> Error in approx(c(0, 0), c(0, 1)) :    need at least two non-NA values
>   to interpolate

There are clearly two non-NA values in these two points so I don't get why I'm receiving this error.

Comment: It seems that the error message is not clearly indicating the problem: there is no variance in `x` (both values are 0). Works fine: `approx(c(0, 1), c(0, 1))` and `approx(c(0, 1), c(0, 0))`

Comment: `x` values should be all different. You are trying to interpolate a *function* (in the mathematical sense): to the same `x` cannot correspond  two `y` values. You are actually providing just one point.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thanks a lot! I'm writing a function to approximate where a horizontal line intersects a polygon made of set of coordinates and it seems like the first edge I tried was completely vertical (lucky me :D)